# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: Discrepancy between programs

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, directory

at the moment I'm writing several tests with Selenium and I use Python.
For rudimentary logging i made this function in order to output all prints to a file:

```
# Datengenerierung für Logname, Kundennummer, Zeit
num_dt = datetime.now()
num_dt_l = num_dt.strftime("%d_%m_%Y %HH_%MM_%SS")
rndnr = str(random.randint(1, 9999))
log_n = r"Logs/" + str(num_dt_l) + "__" + rndnr + r".txt"


# Print-Funktion
def logp(lv1, lv2):
    with redirect_stdout(open(log_n, 'a')):
        print("-----------\n" + str(datetime.now().strftime("%HH:%MM:%SS")) + " " + str(lv1) + " " + str(lv2) + ".")


with redirect_stdout(open(log_n, 'a')):
    print("****************************\nTest", "started\n****************************")

logp("Global Number: " + str(rndnr), "")
logp("Datum ist:", num_dt_l)
```

And in one of two programs it works perfectly fine, however, in another program in the same directory with the very same code it throws following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "Z:\testing\dom\Testing Projects\Project1\chrome_beratung.py", line 37, in 
> with redirect_stdout(open(log_n, 'a')):
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Logs/18_02_2022 12H_44M_20S__2019.txt'

I don't understand how the same code, with the same directory and path would work for one program and not for the other. Can somebody explain how this happens? Does anybody know a solution? Have I overlooked something?

Greetings,
Knolfuns

Comment: *In* the same directory has nothing to do with it: in what directories are these scripts **running**?

Comment: they run both in Project1, the very same folder. I checked the run-options because sometimes when you shuffle around things, it switches to "/etc". Not in this case tho.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to change the file address (log_n variable) to an absolute address  and run the app as root to avoid privilege issues

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).